# Case-Insensitive dictionary not working as expected

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am caching some data in a dictionary from the OsiSoft "PI" system, indexing it by string keys.  The keys come from user-input in a different system, and there is a mix of upper and lower case.  the OsiSoft system keys are case-insensitive, so I need my dictionary to be case insensitive, too.  However, the dictionary is not working as expected.

The dictionary is defined as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, PIPoint> PointsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, PIPoint>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

It is populated from a structure returned from an OsiSoft structure that derives from IList

```
PointsDictionary = RegisteredPoints.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x);
```

When I try to return the PIPoint value from the dictionary, it is not working as expected.  I want to pass the Key in lower, upper or mixed case, and get the same value.

```
    public PIPoint GetPoint(string tag)
    {
        //sfiy-1401a/c6
        //SFIY-1401A/C6
        Debug.WriteLine("sfiy-1401a/c6" + ": " + PointsDictionary.ContainsKey("sfiy-1401a/c6"));
        Debug.WriteLine("SFIY-1401A/C6" + ": " + PointsDictionary.ContainsKey("SFIY-1401A/C6"));
        Debug.WriteLine("Match?" + ": " + "SFIY-1401A/C6".Equals("sfiy-1401a/c6", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (tag == null || !PointsDictionary.ContainsKey(tag)) return null;
        return PointsDictionary[tag];
    }
```

Output from Debugger when running the above:

> sfiy-1401a/c6: False

> SFIY-1401A/C6: True

> Match?: True

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how the case-insensitive dictionary works, or is there something in the way I am populating it (converting IList.ToDictionary()) that means it is not working as intended?

Comment: Nope, you're fundametally misunderstanding how assignment works. You reassign the dictionary to a new (case-sensitive) dictionary rather than adding to the one you created.

Comment: Yes - not a problem with dictionaries, but a "D'Oh" moment on reference types and variable assignment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary is *defined* as case-insensitive, but then you are *overwriting* it with a case-sensitive one.

```
// definition 
Dictionary<string, PIPoint> PointsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, PIPoint>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

// later *reassignment*
PointsDictionary = RegisteredPoints.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x);
```

You see, you're replacing the value! When you overwrite the value, the original comparer is **lost**. You need to specify the comparer again when you call `ToDictionary`. Luckily there is an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__) that takes a key comparer:

```
PointsDictionary = RegisteredPoints.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Note there are also [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__) of `ToDictionary` that take *only* the key selector (and comparer), so you can simplify to:

```
PointsDictionary = RegisteredPoints.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

You can even pass the [original `Comparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.comparer?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_Comparer) so you don't have to remember exactly what type it was:

```
PointsDictionary = RegisteredPoints.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, PointsDictionary.Comparer);
```

Alternatively, you could clear the dictionary and the re-add all the items to it which will preserve the original comparer:

```
PointsDictionary.Clear():
foreach(var p in RegisteredPoints) 
   PointsDictionary[p.Name] = p:
```